# Duda de como leer un archivo .TXT en un codigo secundario del principal - Python

Tags: python

este es mi primer post en esta pagina así que si hay algo mal o incorrecto por favor díganmelo.

Tratare de explicar concisamente lo que estoy tratando de hacer.

Yo tengo un código principal, una carpeta llamada "letras" la cual contiene 10 archivos .txt con una canción dentro de cada archivo (la primera linea es el artista o el nombre de la canción) y por ultimo tengo un código secundario(osea que es llamado por el principal) con el cual yo tengo que trabajar.

Pasare a mostrar el código del archivo secundario así puedo explicar mejor.

```
from configuracion import *
import random
import math
import unicodedata

def lectura(archivo, letra, artistaYcancion): #se queda solo con los oraciones de cierta longitud
    #return (["artista 1","linea 1","linea 2"])
    artistaYcancion=archivo.readline(1)
    for lineas in archivo:
        letra.append(lineas)

def seleccion(letra):#elige uno al azar, devuelve ese y el siguiente
    #return (["linea 1","linea 2"])
```

Lo que yo debo hacer en estas dos funciones que son llamadas por el codigo principal son leer los archivos .txt que son las canciones, y que en pantalla muestre una linea al azar de la letra y la siguiente.

La función lectura es la que se encarga de leer los .txt en la carpeta de listas, intente hacer lo que ven en el código pero por lo que veo no esta bien y ademas no se como hacer para restringir la longitud de las oraciones.

La función selección es la que se encarga de mostrar en pantalla dos oraciones de la letra de la canción, la primera oración la selecciona al azar y la segunda oración es la que le sigue a la primera.

Creo que eso seria todo, si hay alguna duda o algo quedo no muy atendible, por favor comenten y trate de explicar lo mejor posible, la mayoría de cosas que se están preguntando es probable que estén en el programa principal ya configurado por defecto.

Comment: Bienvenido! ¿Pasarías el código del programa principal por favor?

Comment: Además, no entiendo que esperas que devuelva la funcion `lectura`. ¿Qué esperas que devuelva?¿El artista y la letra por separado?¿O esperas que devuelva cada linea del txt en una sola lista?

Answer (score 0):

No entendí muy bien lo que buscas, pero creo que esto tiene que ver. Avísame si te ha servido!

```
import random

archivo = open("letras/[tu archivo].txt")

def lectura(archivo):
    #obtengo las lineas del txt, guardo la primera linea en artistaYcancion y el resto en letras
    #aunque no se que piensas hacer con la variable artistaYcancion
    artistaYcancion, *letra = archivo.read().splitlines()

    #elimino las lineas vacias
    letra = filter(len, letra)

    #devuelvo la letra de la cancion
    return tuple(letra)

def seleccion(letra):
    #obtengo un numero de "oración" aleatoria ej: para obtener la primera index=0
    #se obtiene desde la primer hasta la anteultima oración, ya que si seleccionamos la ultima, no tendremos una segunda que seleccionar. 
    
    index = random.randrange(len(letra)-1)

    #devuelvo una oracion aleatoria y la que le sigue
    return (letra[index], letra[index+1])

print(seleccion(lectura(archivo)))
```